# Why is KFunction2 not a denotable type in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, function-pointers, type-systems

Let's assume we have the following class in Kotlin (version 1.6.21, targeting JVM 17):

```kotlin
interface Cursor(
    fun seekOrNext(target: String): Boolean
    fun seekOrPrevious(target: String): Boolean
)
```

What I would like to do is to accept a function pointer to either one of those methods in a higher-order function:

```kotlin
fun moveCursorAndLog(cursor: Cursor, move: ???, target: String): Boolean {
    println("Moving cursor with ${move.name} to '${target}'.")
    return move(cursor, target)
}
```

The problem is: what's the type we have to insert for `???`

- It cannot be `(Cursor, String) -> Boolean` because that could be any lambda, and we can only call `.name` on a `KFunction`.
- It cannot be `KFunction` either, because that would not allow the call `move(cursor, target)`

If we write this in the IDE:

```
val m = Cursor::seekOrNext
```

... then the type hint will tell us that it is `KFunction2<Cursor, String, Boolean>`, which is **exactly** what we need. However, the following:

```kotlin
fun moveCursorAndLog(cursor: Cursor, move: KFunction2<Cursor, String, Boolean>, target: String): Boolean {
    println("Moving cursor with ${move.name} to '${target}'.")
    return move(cursor, target)
}
```

... doesn't compile because my IntelliJ cannot find the type `KFunction2` anywhere (yes, I made sure that I have `kotlin-reflect` on my classpath).

Which leads me to believe that, while `KFunction2` is a valid type within the Kotlin type system, it is not "denoteable", i.e. we cannot declare a method parameter of this type.

Is that really the case, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except you *can* denote `KFunction2`? IntelliJ doesn't give you autocomplete, but that's just IntelliJ. [Here's](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-6475/Auto-import-and-completion-in-import-statements-dont-work-for-KFunctionN-classes) the bug report for that. `KFunction2` is supposed to be in the `kotlin.reflect` package.

Just do

```
import kotlin.reflect.KFunction2
```

Then you can do:

```
fun moveCursorAndLog(cursor: Cursor, move: KFunction2<Cursor, String, Boolean>, target: String): Boolean {
    println("Moving cursor with ${move.name} to '${target}'.")
    return move(cursor, target)
}
```

This compiles just fine for me.

Of course, just spelling the whole fully qualified name without the import is also fine.

That said, `KFunctionX` are indeed kind of special. They are generated dynamically by the compiler, by [`BuiltInFictitiousFunctionClassFactory.kt`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/92d200e093c693b3c06e53a39e0b0973b84c7ec5/core/descriptors/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/builtins/functions/BuiltInFictitiousFunctionClassFactory.kt), which possibly explains why IntelliJ has the aforementioned bug.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, looks like I simply got fooled by an IDE bug. This makes my code so much nicer now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import kotlin.reflect.KFunction1

interface Cursor {
  fun seekOrNext(target: String): Boolean
  fun seekOrPrevious(target: String): Boolean
}

fun moveCursorAndLog(move: KFunction1<String, Boolean>, target: String): Boolean {
  println("Moving cursor with ${move.name} to '${target}'.")
  return move(target)
}

class CursorImpl : Cursor {

  override fun seekOrNext(target: String): Boolean {
    return true
  }

  override fun seekOrPrevious(target: String): Boolean {
    return true
  }

}

val cursorInstance = CursorImpl()
val move = cursorInstance::seekOrNext
moveCursorAndLog(move, "somewhere else")
// Output: "Moving cursor with seekOrNext to 'somewhere else'."
```